# 'npm rebuild node-sass' results in: error Invalid version: "https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color/-/supports-color-2.0.0.tgz"

Tags: angular, npm, node-sass

My build server compiling an angular app had been working fine until yesterday morning when I started getting this error:

```
npm ERR! Invalid version: "https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color/-/supports-color-2.0.0.tgz"
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\svc-pliska\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-15T16_1
7_08_060Z-debug.log
```

I'm using angular with the packages.json file at the bottom of this question, when I manually run the following npm commands:

```
npm install
npm rebuild node-sass
```

I get this error

```
npm ERR! Invalid version: "https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color/-/supports-color-2.0.0.tgz"
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\svc-pliska\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-15T16_1
7_08_060Z-debug.log
```

And the log file has this error in it:

```
21 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "rebuild" "node-sass"
22 verbose node v8.9.3
23 verbose npm  v5.5.1
24 error Invalid version: "https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color/-/supports-color-2.0.0.tgz"
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

This is the packages.json:

```js
{
  "name": "quick-renew-doctor-portal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --base-href=/ --environment=local",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "headless-build-test": "ng test --browser=ChromeHeadless --single-run=true --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e-local": "ng e2e --base-href=/ --environment=local",
    "e2e-dev": "ng e2e --base-href=/ --environment=dev",
    "ng-build-local": "ng build --environment=local --base-href /",
    "ng-build-dev": "ng build --environment=dev --aot --base-href /",
    "ng-build-staging": "ng build --environment=staging --aot --base-href /",
    "ng-build-production": "ng build --environment=prod --prod --aot --base-href /"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.6",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "6.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.70",
    "@types/video.js": "5.16.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "2.6.1",
    "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.10.2",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "es6-promise": "4.1.1",
    "execSync": "^1.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "howler": "2.0.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-colorbox": "1.6.4",
    "js-base64": "2.1.9",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.7.1",
    "ngx-contextmenu": "1.3.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "text-signature": "1.1.2",
    "typescript-memoize": "1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "video.js": "6.2.5",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.3.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had a carat (^) in the @angular/flex-layout package and I didn't in @angular/cdk and @angular/material. The version of these three packages had to match and a new version of flex-layout came out yesterday making one of the versions not be the same. I removed that carat and used fixed version numbers and everything is good now.

I also removed carats from all other version numbers. I was able to tell what version I was really using by looking at the packages-lock.json file.

Here is how my package.json file looks like now:

```js
{
  "name": "quick-renew-doctor-portal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --base-href=/ --environment=local",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "headless-build-test": "ng test --browser=ChromeHeadless --single-run=true --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e-local": "ng e2e --base-href=/ --environment=local",
    "e2e-dev": "ng e2e --base-href=/ --environment=dev",
    "ng-build-local": "ng build --environment=local --base-href /",
    "ng-build-dev": "ng build --environment=dev --aot --base-href /",
    "ng-build-staging": "ng build --environment=staging --aot --base-href /",
    "ng-build-production": "ng build --environment=prod --prod --aot --base-href /"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.6",
    "@ng-idle/core": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "6.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.70",
    "@types/video.js": "5.16.0",
    "angular2-moment": "1.7.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "2.6.1",
    "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.2",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "d3": "4.12.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "es6-promise": "4.1.1",
    "execSync": "1.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "howler": "2.0.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-colorbox": "1.6.4",
    "js-base64": "2.1.9",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.7.1",
    "ngx-contextmenu": "1.3.4",
    "rxjs": "5.5.5",
    "text-signature": "1.1.2",
    "typescript-memoize": "1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "video.js": "6.2.5",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.3.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  }
}
```